# Unexpected behavior when trying to access StringVar() related to Entry widget using .get()

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Writing my first GUI with Tkinter and running into troubles accessing the StringVar from another method. I obviously found some related threads on this issue on StackExchange but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The stripped-down version needs three pieces for you to replicate. 1.) An empty .csv for selection (can create with "touch inputfile.csv" on *nix or "copy NUL inputfile.csv" on Win). 2.) The provided frontend code; 3.) A minimal module simulation.py also provided (just a few lines).

The unexpected behavior occurs in the invokeSimCode method. Btw, I realize I could stripped down my code snippets even further but as a newbie to Tkinter and OOP, I thought I'd rather err on the side of caution and provide a little more context.

```
"""This module contains the frontend/GUI to the quantitative model."""
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog
import threading
import re
import simulation as sim


# Frequency with which to check if simulation completed
POLLING_DELAY = 250


class MainWindow:
    """Main program window."""

    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title("Model - Main Window")

        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
        self.mainframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.W, tk.E, tk.S))
        # Expands row and/or column 0 if there's extra space
        root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # "Open File" widget
        self.inputFile = tk.StringVar()
        buttonOpenDeals = ttk.Button(
            self.mainframe, text="Open Input File", command=self.fileOpen
        )
        buttonOpenDeals.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

        # Button to run the sim
        self.buttonRun = ttk.Button(
            self.mainframe, text="Run Sim", command=self.invokeSimCode
        )
        self.buttonRun.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
        self.buttonRun.state(["disabled"])

        # Entry widget for rho (correlation parameter)
        ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text="Default Correlation:").grid(
            row=1, column=2, sticky=tk.W
        )
        self.rho = tk.StringVar()
        validatePercentageCMD = self.mainframe.register(self.validatePercentage)
        self.rhoEntry = ttk.Entry(
            self.mainframe,
            width=5,
            textvariable=self.rho,
            validate="key",
            validatecommand=(validatePercentageCMD, "%P"),
        )
        self.rhoEntry.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=tk.W)
        self.rhoEntry.focus()
        ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text="%").grid(row=1, column=4, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E))

        # Labels on input file and computation status
        ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text="Current Input File:").grid(
            row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.W
        )
        self.inputLabel = ttk.Label(self.mainframe, textvariable=self.inputFile)
        self.inputLabel.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E))

        ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text="Status:").grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
        self.statusLabel = ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text="Idle")
        self.statusLabel.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E))

        # Adds a little padding around each widget
        for child in self.mainframe.winfo_children():
            child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

    def fileOpen(self):
        """Implements selection and checking of input file."""
        fname = filedialog.askopenfilename(
            filetypes=[("csv files", "*.csv"), ("All files", "*.*")],
            title="Select File:",
        )
        # Just checking if user actually chose a file (rather than closing the dialog)
        if fname:
            self.inputFile.set(fname)
            self.buttonRun.state(["!disabled"])

    def checkStatus(self, thread):
        """Checks if sim is still running."""
        if thread.is_alive():
            self.mainframe.after(POLLING_DELAY, lambda: self.checkStatus(thread))
        else:
            self.statusLabel.config(text="Idle")

    def invokeSimCode(self):
        """Runs the simulation program, sets status."""
        # Set the value for rho if user provided it (otherwise, standard is used)
        if not self.rho.get():
            sim.RHO = float(self.rho.get()) / 100.0
        else:
            print("I always land in this branch!!!")
        self.statusLabel.config(text="Sim is running, please wait")
        threadedSim = threading.Thread(target=sim.main)
        threadedSim.daemon = True
        threadedSim.start()
        self.mainframe.after(POLLING_DELAY, lambda: self.checkStatus(threadedSim))

    def validatePercentage(self, newval):
        """Checks if the string newval is a percentage with up to two decimal points."""
        return (
            re.match(r"^100(\.0{0,2}?)?$|^\d{0,2}(\.\d{0,2})?$", newval) is not None
            and len(newval) <= 6
        )


def main():
    """Frontend that runs quantitative simulation based on user input."""
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the module simulation.py:

```
import time


# Portfolio data
INPUT_FNAME = "Portfolio123.csv"
# Default correlation
RHO = 0.1


def main():
    print(f"Do something with {RHO} and {INPUT_FNAME}")
    time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried both accessing the StringVar itself as well as the Entry widget, same problem with getting empty string both times.

I did find the suggestion online to only access the contents after the button press to start the "work" procedure so that is already implemented.

Comment: What is the "unexpected behavior"? Are you getting an error? Are you getting the wrong value? Something else?

Comment: I expected that I would be able to read out what is the content of the textvariable after something validated was entered. Obviously, I am thinking about something here incorrectly.

To reproduce:
- Set the text field to something valid, say 50.
- Open a csv with the corresponding button.
- Click the "Run Sim" button.

As pressing the run sim button is what leads to the call of invokeSimCode, I thought the current content of self.rho would be read out. I didn't think self.rho.get() would equal the empty string.

In short, I expect to get 50, but am getting the empty string.

Comment: `if not self.rho.get()` will be true whenever `self.rho` has a value. You'll only go inside that branch of `self.rho` is empty.

Comment: Thank you! Very silly of me to not catch that. Don't have an excuse, don't know how I got to that.